# React: how to execute a function after setState in Parent has been finished

Tags: reactjs, setstate

when the user selects an item in my select box, I update the parent state with a callback function triggered with the handleChange function. after this i want to do something, based on the selected option, however, since setState is async, I dont get the data in time. How do i make sure setState is done before I continue?

parent :

```
class CompareTab extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = { switchListSelected: []}
  }

  updateParentState(data, element){
    this.setState({ [element]: data })
  }
  render(){ return(<SwitchList updateParentState={this.updateParentState} switchListSelected={this.state.switchListSelected}/>)}
}
```

child:

```
class SwitchList extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(option){
    this.props.updateParentState([option], "switchListSelected")
      var url = "http://myserver/switches/snapshots/" + this.props.switchListSelected[0].value
      fetch(url)
  }
```

when i trigger the handleChange

```
> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Comment: Why extract the value from the `props` when it is available via `option` in your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since setState is async, to make sure you get the latest changes on your state you need to work with lifecylces (they are also async). For example, you can use componentDidUpdate() lifecycle.

This is the example of componentDidUpdate lifecycle method:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  //track changes to the previous props and states
  if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind `updateParentState` function in the parent:

You can either do:

```
updateParentState(data, element){
   this.setState({ [element]: data })
}
```

or:

```
<SwitchList updateParentState={() => this.updateParentState()} switchListSelected={this.state.switchListSelected}/>
```

or get it bound to the class in the constructor.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.updateParentState = this.updateParentState.bind(this)
}
```

Once you get the function bound, make sure the array is set in state of parent component - you can do a quick debug with `console.log` in setState's callback. In here, you can make sure setState is done before you continue.

```
this.setState({ [element]: data }, () => { console.log(this.state.switchListSelected) })
```

Comment: And if he for example place console.log after setState, he will not see a new value.

Comment: No, he can see the value in setState's callback.

Comment: setState takes two params, the state variable value & the callback. The callback will reflect the new state change.

Comment: As per his question, he wants to check state is set or not before he proceeds with next.

Comment: This is ugly as hell and you can have a big boilerplate which will be hard to read.
Having everything in a same place as you could in lifecycle functions will make things easier to read and you would do less mistakes.

Comment: The way he is going to structure his code entirely depends on his business logic. All that I'm saying is setState takes a callback, and in that callback, he can see the updated value just to be sure. He has asked where to see the updated value.

Comment: Ok. In his mentioned use case, it is not a problem do have it like that. But, imagine if you have 10-15 setStates in your component, it would be really ugly and unpractical to write callbacks for each setState and handle logic like that.

Comment: @Ryukote, I'm not advocating to use SetState callback to do application/business logic. I just said there's a provision to check updated state. Chill.